# NGXS - Angular 6 Filtering Form actions with the redux devtools plugin/logger

Tags: angular6, ngxs

Is there a way to prevent certain actions from being monitored with the redux devtools plugin?

I noticed there's an option for filtering actions but I'm not sure what to type in there. Method names and action types don't work.

[image]

This is mostly because of the Forms plugin. It's very handy but really pollutes the action list and the console with multiple calls (update form state, update form dirty, etc)

[image]